# How to run PowerShell script with administrator rights from batch file

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch

I want to create a file with PowerShell and did it but I can not run this script from batch file. It just working on where is script located but I want to run this script another machine.

Batch file

`PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""\\169.254.137.118\Shared\Greetings.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"`

PowerShell file

`New-Item C:\Test.txt`

Comment: What error are you getting? What happens or what error do you get when run without the `Verb Runas` parameters?

Comment: There is no error and changes without runas parameter. The PS just opens then closes.

Comment: It's just working on local machine. I want to run this script on my machine.

Comment: How about running it in this format `PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""\\169.254.137.118\Shared\Greetings.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"` and also try that same format without the `-Verb RunAs` and see what happens. Perhaps you need to bypass execution policy on the initial call before the other powershell call within it.

Answer (score 0):

The batch file must be Run as Administrator to start with.

There is no way for a non-administrator batch file to elevate itself
to administrator status.

---

If this is already the case and you only wish `powershell.exe`
to wait for the
[Start-Process command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3)
to finish, you need to add the `-Wait` parameter.

Also see the advice in the post
[How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next)

Comment: As you said. It is already elevated.

Comment: Then it's normal for the PowerShell command to start the process and finish itself, as the process is then run independently. If you want it to wait, add the `-Wait` parameter. Also see the advice in the post [How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next).

Comment: It's just working on local machine. I want to run this script on my machine.

Comment: See my above comment.

Comment: Sorry, not working with this. It not creating the file on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note:
If you compile the BAT file as an EXE, the program will automatically run as administrator.